Visual studio 2022 freezing when opening any solution
Hey my Visual studio is freezing everytime i open any solution even newly created once.
Btw im running on win10.
I reinstalled vs twice already with no success.
I updated my .net with no success.
and i updated my graphics driver also with no success.

Please try the following steps to fix the VS freeze issue:
1: Open the VS 2022 Developer Command Prompt and use the following command to start VS in safe mode:
devenv.exe /SafeMode
If the freeze no longer occurs in safe mode, it may be caused by an extension.
2: Navigate to the project directory and delete the .vs file.
3: Delete the ComponentModelCache folder to clean up the Visual Studio cache. The path is as follows:
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<version number>\ComponentModelCache
4: Run the repair function through the Visual Studio Installer.
5: Some background processes or third-party software (such as antivirus software, system optimization software) may interfere with Visual Studio. You can temporarily disable or uninstall these software for testing.
6: If none of the above methods work, open the VS 2022 Developer Command Prompt and enter the following command to capture the VS activity log:
devenv /log "\Path_to_store_logs\xxx.xml"
After opening the VS here, please reproduce this issue, and finally turn off VS to upload the generated logs.
